# splitting the results of a regular expression

Tags: java

With the following code I was able to get all the necessary information out of a form, this information is;

```
n = 5
p = 0.5
lambda = 0.3
d = 1
n = 8
p = 0.1
d = 1
p = 0.3
```

I put all this information in a HashMap, but what I actually need would be 6 hashmaps; like this

```
Hashmap 1
n = 5
p = 0.5
Hashmap 2
lambda = 0.3
Hashmap 3
d = 1
Hashmap 4
n = 8
p = 0.1
Hashmap 5
d = 1
Hashmap 6
p = 0.3
```

In other words, always when I get an n as keyword, the next keyword and value should also be stored in this Hashmap, this next keyword will always be an p.

I know it is not really possible to split a Hashmap, but I can't find any other way

Thanks a lot

```
public static void main(String[] args ) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException        
{
     File filename = new File("H:\\NetBeansProjects\\thesis2.0\\src\\thesis2\\pkg0\\txt-files\\formulier.txt");

     try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) 
     {

        HashMap hm = new HashMap();

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s+(\\w+)\\s+([0-9.]+)\\s*");
        for (String line; (line = in.readLine()) != null; ) 
        {
            Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
            if (m.matches()) 
            {
                String keyword = m.group(1);
                String parameter = m.group(2);

                hm.put(m.group(1),m.group(2));

                System.out.println(m.group(1) + " = " + m.group(2));
            }
       }
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `List<>` to store the `Map<>`s, you basicly need to create a simple token based parser for the values that dispatches it to the next `Map`.

```
List<Map<String,String>> motherList = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String,String> workingChild = new HashMap<>();

.... 

String keyword = m.group(1);
String parameter = m.group(2);

workingChild.put(keyword,parameter);
if(!keyword.equals("n")) {
    motherList.add(workingChild);
    workingChild = new HashMap<>();
}
```

We basically have 1 motherlist containing al our child maps, for every input keyword and parameter, we put it in our current work map, and then we put it in the `motherMap` ONLY if the last token wasn't "n".

Comment: thank you for your answer, I was wondering if this would work because in the list their is always added a map workingChild, will this not override the previous made Hashmap, also called workingChild ?

Comment: @StudentX [Java is always pass by value](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40499/1542723), so our resulting HashMap will be put in the list, and we can then reuse the reference `workingChild` without affecting the Map in the List.